# draw custom edge with open arc in tikz-er

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge

I'm trying to draw an edge with an open arc in tikz(-er) looking like the one on the picture attached:

[image: talking about the relationship/edge between Secret Lair and Secret Island Lair]

Thanks in advance,
Uncle Cuppa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/arc/.style={code={
    \draw (-0.1,0.15) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3]    (-0.1,-0.15);}}]
 \draw[very thick,blue] (1,1) -- (0,0)  pic[pos=0.5,sloped,allow upside down] {arc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use e.g. `decorations.markings` or `arrows.meta` but this solution here does not require any libraries.

**ADDENDUM**: Of course, you can make this a style that you can pass to an `edge`. I called the style `sunset`, and you can use it e.g. like

```
\draw[very thick,blue] (1,1) edge[supset] (0,0);
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/supsetarc/.style={code={
    \draw (-0.1,0.15) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=3]    (-0.1,-0.15);}},
    pics/subsetarc/.style={code={
    \draw (0.1,0.15) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=3]    (0.1,-0.15);}},
    supset/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- 
    pic[pos=0.5,sloped,allow upside down] {supsetarc} (\tikztotarget)}},
    subset/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- 
    pic[pos=0.5,sloped,allow upside down] {subsetarc} (\tikztotarget)}}]
 \draw[very thick,blue] (1,1) edge[supset] (0,0);
 \draw[very thick,blue] (2,1) edge[subset] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what I need! Thanks!