# given two nodes, how to define a custom edge style that draws a circular arc instead of a segment joining the two?

Tags: shapes, edge, custom

Given two points A and B (left), I need to draw a beam that looks like this:

[image] i.e. end points of the arc are defined by the nodes, with some specific angle that I can specify.

e.g using [draw custom edge with open arc in tikz-er](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518134/draw-custom-edge-with-open-arc-in-tikz-er) as a related starting point, I perhaps may use to generate above

> \draw[very thick,blue] (A.center) edge[supset] (B.center);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a style `beam={<color>}{<angle>}` that can be used in a `\draw` command.

[image]

Using `show path construction` (from the `decorations.pathreplacing` library), you can refer to `(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)` and `(\tikzinputsegmentlast)`, which are the initial and terminal points of the given path. The coordinate `$(\tikzinputsegmentlast)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$` (uses the `calc` library) is the "vector" from the initial point to the terminal point.

The command `let\p1=(<coordinate>)` automatically assigns the x and y coordinates to `\x1` and `\y1`.

Use `atan2` to compute the arctangent, which gives you the coordinates of the ends of the arcs. The length of the vector is computed with `veclen`. You could use `\n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)+4mm}` if you want to extend 4mm beyond the terminal point, or `\n2={1.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)}` if you want the length scaled by a factor of 1.5.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\tikzset{
    beam/.style 2 args={
        decorate,
        decoration={show path construction, 
            lineto code={
                \fill[opacity=.5, #1] 
                let\p1=($(\tikzinputsegmentlast)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$), 
                \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}, \n2={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in 
                (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)--($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)+(\n1-.5*#2:\n2)$) 
                arc (\n1-.5*#2:\n1+.5*#2:\n2)--cycle;
            }
        }
    },
    beam/.default={black}{90},
    dot/.style={fill, circle, gray, minimum size=2mm, inner sep=0pt}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[dot, label=below:A](A) at (0,0){};
\node[dot, label=above:B](B) at (-1,1){};
\node[dot, label=above:C](C) at (1,1){};

\draw[beam={orange}{60}](A.center)--(B.center);
\draw[beam={red}{30}](A.center)--(C.center);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for such a prompt and working solution! Is there a way I could extend the beam length to twice or some factor k times the length AB (i.e. starting from A, but arc radius going beyond B?) 

Also, could you help me understand/read the code you have supplied? I mean let me kindly know reference material/manual which helps me I understand your solution (I need to learn to fish than getting a fish everytime ;) ), or perhaps elaborate your solution here and I take it from there.

Comment: ok, changing to veclen(2*\x1,2*\y1) made the beam twice as long... :) 

I wonder if color fading could be applied from origin A to the end of the beam.

Comment: @user184238: I added some explanation. I will try to get fading added later today (or maybe someone else will do it first).